# Lemma about ordinal arithmetic

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to prove the following lemma:
For any three ordinals $\alpha, \alpha' >0$, $\beta >1$, if $\alpha > \alpha'$, then we have
$$
\beta^\alpha > \beta^{\alpha'} \cdot \delta + \gamma
$$
For $0 < \delta < \beta$ and $\gamma < \beta^{\alpha'}$.

My question is, is this even true, and if so what is the best way to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note that $$\beta^\alpha\geq\beta^{\alpha'+1}=\beta^{\alpha'}\cdot \beta\geq\beta^{\alpha'}\cdot (\delta+1)=\beta^{\alpha'}\cdot\delta+\beta^{\alpha'}>\beta^{\alpha'}\cdot\delta+\gamma.$$